# html2canvs how to loop or reuse for multiple div/html dom elements

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to use html2canvas integrating with jspdf for printing multiple tabs.

```
  printTabsManual() {
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="GRID_ID-pane"]');
    console.log(tabs.length);
    //const pdf = new jsPDF();
    //console.log(max_h);
    //console.log(max_w);
    let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', [max_h, max_w]);
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      html2canvas(tabs[i])
      .then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
      });
    }
    pdf.save("Download.pdf");
  }
```

I am able to get the tab's div using the query selector, and this code without the loop works really fine if you are dealing with a single div, but it breaks or maybe the implementation is not right for the multiple looping.

I tried to see the logs, it's not able to get the image for second tab's div.

Not sure where I am getting this wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop executing an async operation... I believe you untended to execute all of your async tasks and only then to proceed.. so.. let's use `Promise.all` for that purpose:

```
const tasks = tabs.map(tab => html2canvas(tab))

Promise.all(tasks).then(canvases =>
{
   for (const canvas of canvases)
   {
       const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
       pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
   }

   pdf.save("Download.pdf");
})
```

**Which means:** execute all async tasks, then manipulate their results and save pdf